# Maps with Api key not showing the Map

Tags: android, react-native, android-mapview, api-key, react-native-maps

I have been struggling with this map issue for days now still can now find the problem please I will really need help with this issues, I built my mobile app with **Expo**, in one of my details screen I want to display the map, when I test on android emulator **screen A** but on my mobile **screen B** it is not showing:

[image]

I have added the apiKey to my `app.json` see below:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#fcfcfc"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/images/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp",
      "versionCode": 4,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#4628a8"
      },
      "config":{
        "googleMaps":{
          "apiKey":"AIzaSyANZkUljyqBPFMaTVaaP3c4-NFxyrjxuZY"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "rgtDhsgf-0984-8928-r674-rYtfg8565854a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the details screen I import `react-native-maps` and include `PROVIDER_GOOGLE` where the map is `Details.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'

const Details = ({ navigation, route }) => {
 return (
                    <View style={styles.mapCover}>
                        <MapView
                            style={styles.mapInner}
                            initialRegion={{
                                latitude: 6.4251323,
                                longitude: 3.4268301,
                                latitudeDelta: 0.0063,
                                longitudeDelta: 0.0063,
                            }}
                            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        />
                   </View>
)
}

export default Details
```

Thanks for your help, I appreciate..